# function onload attribute (bufferloader)

Tags: function, onload, web-audio-api

I am using a bufferloader.js file to load and play multiple audio tracks at the same time (in Web Audio). The code for the `BufferLoader` is as follows:

```
function BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback) {
   this.context = context;
   this.urlList = urlList;
   this.onload = callback;
   this.bufferList = new Array();
   this.loadCount = 0;
}

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function() {
   for (var i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
   this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
}

loadBuffer(){....}
```

Can someone explain what `this.onload` is? I'm unable to find anything about onload properties for functions.

The issue with this `BufferLoader` class is that every time I want to reload the buffer, I have to instantiate a new `BufferLoader` in order for the callback to call properly. Can someone advise me on a better way to create this callback so that I can reuse the `BufferLoader` class?